# Node require: unload module successful but memory usage still high

Tags: node.js

Im using require to import modules containing long arrays.

After use i am successfully clearing the cache and removing the deleting the array but on each new required module my memory usage is increasing.

How do i prevent this?

**** EDITED*****
code added

```
 Array1.map(function(val,index){


          var requiredModuke = require("../moduleLocation/"+index)

          var path = resolve.sync("../moduleLocation/"+index);
          if (path){
            console.log("Path to module found:", path);
          }


              setTimeout( function(){


              delete require.cache[require.resolve(path)]

              var numOfModulesLoaded= Object.keys(require.cache).length

              console.log(numOfModulesLoaded)



              },index*8000 );


    })
```

Comment: You will have to show us the relevant code (what you think you are removing) and describe exactly how you are measuring the memory usage.  Heap snapshots are the most useful way to see how much memory the Javascript interpreter is actually using and it can also tell you what the main objects are in that heap.  When looking at total process memory, you cannot tell how much of that is actually in use vs. freed from the interpreter and ready to be re-allocated when needed.n  There are lots of ways people are fooled about what they are seeing or where the issue is without measuring properly.

Comment: Added code, Monitoring using activity monitor. Also if i leave this for more than 50 runs of the loop, node quits with err FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Answer (score 2):

node.js caches the modules, you need to delete from the cache in order to free the memory.

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('ModulePath/ModuleName')]
```

to check all cached/loaded  modules

```
console.log(require.cache);
```

Comment: thanks but i am doing this already, i added code and stil running out of memory